# Unable to access span tag's innerHTML in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to create an email message (when a user clicks a link) whose body is pre-filled with text from an asp:Literal. The HTML is written as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="../../images/Question.gif" alt="Q" />
        Q:
        <span id="question"><asp:Literal ID="literalQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../../images/Answer.gif" alt="Q" />
        A:
        <span id="answer"><asp:Literal ID="literalAnswer" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Click <a href="#" onclick="javaScript:emailWrongInfo()">Here</a> to email.
    </td>
</tr>
```

I also have a JavaScript function that opens an email message when the user clicks the email link:

```
function emailWrongInfo() {
            window.location="mailto:Test@test.com?Subject=Email%20Notification&Body=Question:%0A" + document.getElementById("question").innerHTML+ "%0A%0AAnswer:%0A" + document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
    }
```

When I click the link, the new email message opens, but the question and answer are not filled in in the body portion. It seems like the span's text is not being pulled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change textContent for innerHTML

Comment: I tried the innerHTML, and when I click the link, I get the following alert dialog:
"The command link argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using."

Comment: try instead of put it directly in the string put it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HTMLElementObject.innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) instead of elementNode.textContent.

**HTMLElementObject.innerHTML is used to get the inner HTML of an element While textContent property returns or sets the text from the selected element.**

```
function emailWrongInfo() {
            window.location="mailto:Test@test.com?Subject=Email%20Notification&Body=Question:%0A" + document.getElementById("question").innerHTML+ "%0A%0AAnswer:%0A" + document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
    }
```

Hope, it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing:

```
    document.getElementById("question").textContent
```

to

```
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML
```